# Add Metadata to jpg image with PHP and Image Magik (EXIF, IDF)

Tags: php, sharepoint, imagemagick, exif

I wrote a class that handles converting .PSD's uploaded to a folder into .JPG's so I can display them on a website. It uses a combination of PHP's file functions and IMAGE MAGIK to do the conversion and file moving.

Recently I was asked to add a feature to this system to handle writing out "Tags" to each JPG's metadata so that MS SHAREPOINT could index the images and filter them based on certain tags.

I've done a little research and I can't seem to find an easy way to add meta data to a JPG either through IMAGE MAGIK's class functions or in PHP.

This is the process with some code snippets.

Images uploaded to a folder -> After each upload a command line image magick script runs on each image that does the following.

```
        public function resizeImage($from, $to = $this->holdingdDir, $size = "945x945") {
        $command = "\"C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-6.8.7-Q16\\convert.exe\" ";
            exec($command.$from." -profile \"C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-6.8.7-Q16\\AdobeRGB1998.icc\" -flatten -resize ".$size."x".$size." ".$to, $aOutput, $retVal);
        return array(
            "command" => $command.$from." ".$to,
            "from" => $from,
            "to" => $to,
            "output" => $aOutput,
            "return" => $retVal
        );
    }
```

Once the image is converted to a JPG and moved to the holding directory, another script picks it up and moves it to it's final location on the web server.

```
 public function send($source, $file, $dest, $perms='0777') {
    return ftp_put($this->connection, $this->basePath.$dest."/".$file, $source, FTP_BINARY);
}
```

I'm assuming there is some way to write out meta data to a file you create but I'm not having much luck finding out how. I've included a screen shot of the "meta data" I want to edit, it's the same data fields that show up when you right click and image in Windows and select "properties-->details"

[image: MS File details]

Any help/guidance would be great,

Thanks

*UPDATE*
After doing some more research I think the data I want to edit is called " EXIF - IDF" data? I am still struggling to find a plugin or library that handles writing this data easily.